# Ubuntu experience feels sluggish on modern hardware

Tags: ubuntu, performance, x-windows, ubuntu-unity

I've installed Ubuntu on my home workstation (HP Z400 with ATI Radeon HD 5800). At the mercy of the prompt, I agreed to installing the *ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver*. One would think that the system should be quite snappy, but far from it - there are numerous problems with visuals. For example the login screen has a **fade in animation** which **takes a lot longer** than it should, and **dragging windows about feels like some steps are not being rendered**.

The Ati Catalyst Control Center appears to function correctly, and let me setup dual monitors without any problems. What should I do to fix this behavior? I can only assume that there's a pro *"make my ubuntu snappy"* switch somewhere. I've tried searching the interwebs, but I was only able to find old results, which suggested turning off tripple buffers. I found no such configuration in the Ati Catalyst Control Center app.

**glxinfo** output:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions: *SOME*
client glx vendor string: ATI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions: *SOME*
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions: *SOME*
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.1.10665 Compatibility Profile Context
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL extensions: *SOME*
```

Comment: From the GRUB boot menu, try running Memtest86+.  Evaluate the memory rates and timings.

Answer (score 1):

It could be Ubuntu itself. Did you have dual boot? If so, is the other OS showing the same behavior? If so, it's a hardware issue

How long has this been happening for? Is it since your dual monitor was put in? If so, try unplugging it and restarting.

If you can I would try uninstalling ATI Catalyst Control Center.

And if all else fails, you could try reinstalling Ubuntu.